# Undefined reference to RSA_* but compiling with -lcrypto

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, cross-compiling, u-boot

I am trying to compile u-boot for the licheepi zero with `make LicheePi_Zero_defconfig`

However when I compile the bootloader using: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -V=1`

I get this error:

```
  cc   -o tools/dumpimage tools/aisimage.o tools/atmelimage.o tools/fit_common.o tools/fit_image.o tools/image-host.o tools/boot/image-fit.o tools/image-sig-host.o tools/boot/image-fit-sig.o tools/boot/image-cipher.o tools/boot/fdt_region.o tools/boot/bootm.o tools/lib/crc32.o tools/default_image.o tools/lib/fdtdec_common.o tools/lib/fdtdec.o tools/boot/image.o tools/boot/image-host.o tools/imagetool.o tools/imximage.o tools/imx8image.o tools/imx8mimage.o tools/kwbimage.o tools/lib/md5.o tools/lpc32xximage.o tools/mxsimage.o tools/omapimage.o tools/os_support.o tools/pblimage.o tools/pbl_crc32.o tools/vybridimage.o tools/stm32image.o tools/lib/rc4.o tools/rkcommon.o tools/rkimage.o tools/rksd.o tools/rkspi.o tools/socfpgaimage.o tools/sunxi_egon.o tools/lib/crc16-ccitt.o tools/lib/hash-checksum.o tools/lib/sha1.o tools/lib/sha256.o tools/lib/sha512.o tools/common/hash.o tools/ublimage.o tools/zynqimage.o tools/zynqmpimage.o tools/zynqmpbif.o tools/lib/fdt-libcrypto.o tools/sunxi_toc0.o tools/libfdt/fdt.o tools/libfdt/fdt_ro.o tools/libfdt/fdt_wip.o tools/libfdt/fdt_sw.o tools/libfdt/fdt_rw.o tools/libfdt/fdt_strerror.o tools/libfdt/fdt_empty_tree.o tools/libfdt/fdt_addresses.o tools/libfdt/fdt_overlay.o tools/gpimage.o tools/gpimage-common.o tools/mtk_image.o tools/mtk_nand_headers.o tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o tools/lib/rsa/rsa-verify.o tools/lib/rsa/rsa-mod-exp.o tools/lib/aes/aes-encrypt.o tools/lib/aes/aes-decrypt.o tools/dumpimage.o   -lcrypto -lssl
tools/sunxi_toc0.o: In function `toc0_verify_header':
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x4f0): undefined reference to `RSA_set0_key'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x507): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x525): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x5eb): undefined reference to `RSA_set0_key'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x702): undefined reference to `RSA_set0_key'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x719): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x725): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x742): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0x74e): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e'
tools/sunxi_toc0.o: In function `toc0_set_header':
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xa95): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_d'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xaee): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_d'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xd71): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xd99): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xdd9): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xe01): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf04): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_n'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf19): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf2b): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_e'
sunxi_toc0.c:(.text+0xf40): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `prepare_ctx':
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `EC_GROUP_order_bits'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `ecdsa_check_signature.isra.3':
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x3ad): undefined reference to `ECDSA_SIG_set0'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `ecdsa_sign':
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x497): undefined reference to `ECDSA_SIG_get0'
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x4ae): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad'
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x4c0): undefined reference to `BN_bn2binpad'
tools/lib/ecdsa/ecdsa-libcrypto.o: In function `ecdsa_add_verify_data':
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x68d): undefined reference to `EC_GROUP_order_bits'
ecdsa-libcrypto.c:(.text+0x6d3): undefined reference to `EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates'
tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o: In function `rsa_sign':
rsa-sign.c:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o: In function `rsa_get_params':
rsa-sign.c:(.text+0x95a): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_key'
rsa-sign.c:(.text+0x9a9): undefined reference to `RSA_get0_key'
tools/lib/rsa/rsa-sign.o: In function `rsa_add_verify_data':
rsa-sign.c:(.text+0xf18): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scripts/Makefile.host:104: recipe for target 'tools/dumpimage' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/dumpimage] Error 1
Makefile:1883: recipe for target 'tools' failed
make: *** [tools] Error 2
```

It seems that the linker cannot find the -lcrypto library, but this flag is set at the end of the compilation statement`cc   -o tools/dumpimage ..... -lssl -lcrypto`

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: In your comments you say that the compilation statement is `-lssl -lcrypto` but in fact if you look at it, your link line actually uses `-lcrypto -lssl`.  Maybe you need to fix the order?  I'm not sure about how these two libraries interact but I've only ever seen them used as `-lssl -lcrypto` (and, order of libraries on the link line **IS** critical and important).

Comment: I just compiled changing the order, but I get the same error

Comment: Well, that wasn't the problem then.  It's not the case that it can't find the `libcrypto` library, because if the linker couldn't find it you'd get an error saying it wasn't found.  Apparently the version of the `libcrypto` library that is found, doesn't have those symbols.  Maybe the version of OpenSSL installed on the system is too old.  I didn't check all the symbols above, but I do note that `BN_bn2binpad` for example doesn't appear to be available in OpenSSL 1.0.2 (or older).  You need OpenSSL 1.1.1 (or newer) to get it.